# Auto run android app fails because reboot disabled all "third party" applications

Tags: android

I can't seem to find anything on this, but I'm trying to get an application to run right away once an android device has finished booting up. the problem is that when i hold the power button, then tap "Reboot", i get a message saying

"Reboot System
Do you wish to reboot the system? This will disable all third party applications you have installed"

So the options are cancel and ok. But I don't want to disable all third party applications because my application should automatically start when the device is rebooted. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening and how i should prevent my application from being disabled on reboot?

Comment: What version of Android are you running? Does the same message appear when you shutdown instead of reboot?

Comment: I'm silly, you were right Wash, i just needed to click Shutdown rather than reboot, and give the app about half a minute after it boot up and it ran

Comment: Just curious to know, which version of android are you using ? Which manufacturer ?

Comment: oh sorry, i deleted that comment, i'm using 4.4.2. i don't remember the manufacturer right now, i've already passed on the tablet to the higher ups. after the device finishes booting up though, it takes around 1 - 1.5 minutes for the app to start up